# Difference between vertical shear and vertical extension linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am relatively new to linear algebra, and I am having trouble understanding what the geometric difference between vertical extension and vertical shear is.

For example, the dot product of the vector [3,0] and the standard matrix for vertical shearing with a scale factor of 3 , results in the vector [3,9]. After placing these two points on the coordinate system, it seems to me that the vector has been vertically extended. My confusion is because of the fact that the dot products between the standard matrices and vectors result in vectors, yet both the initial vector and the vector after the transformation are represented as planes and the moving vertices of a plane. Why is this?

Comment: Those terms, vertical extension and vertical shear, are not defined in linear algebra.  You seem to want to apply them in the context of plane geometry using Cartesian coordinates.  It would be okay to ask a Question in that context, but you should not expect Readers to tell you what you mean; you are the expert on that.  Phrases like "the dot product of the standard matrrix and the vector being transformed" would be clearer if you used mathematical notation.  See this [brief introduction to posting here with math notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: Is there any way you can present your idea in notations. I really can't understand what you are asking.....